# Upgrading to Django 4.0.1 from Django 3.2.10 - "got both positional and keyword arguments for field" error message

Tags: python, django, django-upgrade

I'm trying to update a Django project from version 3.2.10 to 4.0.1

When running the tests, I'm getting this error:

```
File "/Users/akira/Projects/work/speedy/cash_flow/jobs/bank_account/process_flinks_transactions_job.py", line 63, in __init__
    super(ProcessFlinksTransactionsJob, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/akira/.local/share/virtualenvs/speedy-kJQJ8v9W/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 446, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: ProcessFlinksTransactionsJob() got both positional and keyword arguments for field 'name'.
```

The code that's raising the error is:

```
class ProcessFlinksTransactionsJob(Job):
objects = ProcessFlinksTransactionsJobManager()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update({"name": ProcessFlinksTransactionsJob.__name__})

    super(ProcessFlinksTransactionsJob, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

How would I go about fixing this error?

Comment: What's the value of `args` and `kwargs` here? Is `name` already being provided by `args` before you add it to `kwargs`?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this today, and while Mariusz's solution makes sense, sometimes you may use the object without saving it.

This is triggered because when a model is loaded from db, it is instantiated by [new = cls(*values)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L539). If your **init** sets a field with a keyword, the change introduced in [#22640](https://github.com/django/django/commit/73b1b225ce1a3318d4478f90cc0db0a260aba3aa) will raise the error when an object is created from the db (as it is probably in your tests).

[The fix that worked for me](https://github.com/math-a3k/django-ai/commit/33bc39c307c47222de34dae08f44721b5721b59c) is to set the fields on **init** only if there are not args.

In your case it would be:

```
class ProcessFlinksTransactionsJob(Job):
    objects = ProcessFlinksTransactionsJobManager()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not args:
             kwargs.update({"name": ProcessFlinksTransactionsJob.__name__})
        super(ProcessFlinksTransactionsJob, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way the objects gets instantiated correctly when loaded from db and can be created programmatically and keep the current behaviour.

Hope it works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a relevant thread on DjangoProject, see it [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33307#comment:4).

As a comment says:

> It's an intended change, see [73b1b225ce1a3318d4478f90cc0db0a260aba3aa](https://github.com/django/django/commit/73b1b225ce1a3318d4478f90cc0db0a260aba3aa). This error was added to prevent misconfigurations when values for the same fields are passed in `args` and `kwargs` as in your case. I'd recommend moving this logic to the `save()`.

I have nothing else but to agree with Mariusz Felisiak :)